# How does one get the order prefix programmatically?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, prefix

We use separate order prefixes for our production and lower environments. For each environment we run a sequel statement to update so each environment is unique.

```
update `sales_sequence_profile` set prefix = "PREFIX";
```

How would I return the prefix value programmatically?

I am currently working on Magento 2.2.10

Answer (score 0):

A peer figured this out so I am answering in hopes to benefit others.

Include the following classes and handle dependency injection in _constructor.

```
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\ResourceModel\Profile;
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\ResourceModel\Meta;
```

Here is function to get prefix:

```
 /**
     * get Order prefix
     */
    protected function getOrderPrefix()
    {
        try {
            $metaId = $this->_meta->loadByEntityTypeAndStore('order', $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical(
                sprintf("[%s]: Meta not found for Order prefix.",
                    strtoupper($this->queueType)
                )
            );
            return;
        }

        try {
            $collection = $this->_profile->loadActiveProfile($metaId->getId());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical(
                sprintf("[%s]: profile not found for Order prefix.",
                    strtoupper($this->queueType)
                )
            );
            return;
        }
        return $collection->getPrefix();
    }
```

cheers!!